# Wordpress: woocommerce creating cookie that is not allowing my site to be cached via varnish

Tags: wordpress, cookies, woocommerce, varnish, pantheon

I have a 4.9.6 wordpress site hosted on pantheon. I am trying to leverage there varnish cache feature provided by pantheon but I am running into problems with a cookie being set site-wide for anon users that is not allowing my site to cache. When I run

curl -I dev-example.pantheonsite.io in terminal the output is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Link: <http://dev-example.pantheonsite.io/wp-json/>;     rel="https://api.w.org/"
Link: <https://example.me/xxxxx>; rel=shortlink
Server: nginx
Set-Cookie: SESS493517e45081d627fb825d332c442179=6598ca6c993e2d779127efcc27c022e6; path=/;       domain=.dev-example.pantheonsite.io; HttpOnly
X-Pantheon-Styx-Hostname: styx-fe1-a-74cb6bb89d-mzdm6
X-Styx-Req-Id: styx-1cd2c5b9a35cd4232543231dd5bb1736
Via: 1.1 varnish
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Wed, 30 May 2018 21:11:56 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-mdw17350-MDW, cache-dfw18628-DFW
X-Cache: MISS, MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0, 0
X-Timer: S1527714713.844595,VS0,VE3179
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Cookie, Cookie
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
```

After I disable the woocomerce plugin the cookie is gone and page caching works. The only help I have found from google is adjusting my varnish settings which can not be done by me on pantheon. Any other ideas/work around? I have gone back and forth with pantheons customer support and they told me I need to come up with a solution. Surely people are running woo on pantheon and are able to leverage varnish.

PS You can probably tell I am new to varnish :)

Comment: As a side note to my answer below, I've tried hosting with pantheon, and whilst their service is good from a development standpoint (probably the best cloud hosting for devs) it's also really rather slow compared to hosts like Kinsta. It also doesn't scale well, unless you start paying exorbitant sums of money.

Comment: @jpshayes - Did you ever find a good solution to this?  I've been running in circles with Pantheon trying to find a reasonable workaround as well and I'm getting the same "you need to come up with a solution".  I've been looking at creating a MU plugin for selectively load our Stripe integration on a single page or offloading the transactions page to a subdomain as a last resort, but trying to find a cleaner solution if one's been come up with.  Google searches are coming up empty so far.

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce has a resource specifically for this problem.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/configuring-caching-plugins/#section-5

<-- EDIT -->

I realise that it's all to do with configuring varnish, not Wordpress, but what needs to be understood here is that the fix can't be done from the Wordpress/WC end of things. Varnish needs to be configured so that it passes through woocommerce pages.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The cookie is being set on all pages. Not just woo pages.

Comment: If you'd read my comment fully (after the edit) you'd see that it doesn't matter that it's on all pages, it's a varnish issue, not wordpress. If you have no access to configure varnish then you won't be able to fix it.